# \Aboxed with multiple & in align* environment

Tags: equations, align

`\Aboxed` command in `mathtools` is used to box an equation with only one alignment operator inside.

But how to box an equation with multiple align operators ?

For instance, in the following equations, how can I box one complete equation?

---

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
&\therefore&  \theta_1 & >  \theta_0 \\
&\Rightarrow&  P+\frac{1}{\rho}\sigma_n^2 & > \rho\sigma_n^2 \\
\Aboxed{&\Rightarrow&\frac{P}{\sigma_n^2}} & >  \frac{\rho^2-1}{\rho} \\
 \end{align*}
 \end{frame}
________________
```

---

Comment: `\Aboxed` can only have one `&` inside, because the macro is defined such that it reads all content up to the `&` and the content from the `&` to the end. Then the both parts are put into an `\fbox` and shifted right (by measuring the second half) such that they align with the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't automatic, but it works.  It `\rlap`s an `\fbox`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
&\therefore&  \theta_1 & >  \theta_0 \\
&\Rightarrow&  P+\frac{1}{\rho}\sigma_n^2 & > \rho\sigma_n^2 \\
\rlap{\fbox{\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{25pt}\rule{170pt}{0pt}}}&\Rightarrow&\frac{P}{\sigma_n^2}
& >  \frac{\rho^2-1}{\rho} \\
 \end{align*}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

FOLLOW UP:

To make the box only around the equation,  move it right a few alignment tabs and shorten the horizontal rule length.  I also did a negative kern to add some padding.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
&\therefore&  \theta_1 & >  \theta_0 \\
&\Rightarrow&  P+\frac{1}{\rho}\sigma_n^2 & > \rho\sigma_n^2 \\
&\Rightarrow&\rlap{\kern-1ex\fbox{\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{25pt}\rule{62pt}{0pt}}}
\frac{P}{\sigma_n^2}& >  \frac{\rho^2-1}{\rho} \\
 \end{align*}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I need to make a box only around the equation excluding implies sign.

Comment: @kaka Please see FOLLOW UP in my revision.