# Box part of equation in align environment

Tags: align, amsmath, boxes

I want to box, as an answer, an equation of the `align*` environment. Not sure how to do it.

```
\begin{align*}
(1+2i)z_2&=-11(2-i)\\
z_2&=\dfrac{11(i-2)}{1+2i}\\
z_2&=11i
\end{align*}
```

I have tried `\boxed{z_2&=11i}`, but it failed.

Comment: load `mathtools`-package and use `\Aboxed{}`

Comment: If your box needs to span more than one alignment point in the future, then this question may be of use: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223511/aboxed-with-multiple-in-align-environment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `\Aboxed` macro from the [`mathtools`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package to have a box around a single alignment point `&`, i.e. a single line in your case:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  (1+2i)z_2&=-11(2-i)\\
  z_2&=\dfrac{11(i-2)}{1+2i}\\
  \Aboxed{z_2&=11i}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This is for an individual line in an alignment, as far as I know.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, I thought that was what OP was after, seeing as he tried `\boxed{...}`. The frame around the output is added later, I will change that to make it clearer :)