# Boxed and colored a two-line equation

Tags: equations, boxes, beamerposter, box

I have the following mwe. I want to color and box only the equation except the equation number. I tried using **{\color{} }** and **\mybox{}** but they didn't work. Any help is much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 
\frac{(-1)^k(\alpha+k+\frac12) \sin \sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+k+\frac12)^2}}{(\beta^2+(2k+1)^2)\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+k+\frac12)^2}} \\
&=\frac{\pi(\alpha+\frac12 i \beta)\sin\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}{4i\beta\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2}\beta)\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}
-
\frac{\pi(\alpha-\frac12 i \beta)\sin\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha-\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}{4i\beta\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2}\beta)\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha-\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{empheq,
            amssymb}
\usepackage[dvipsname]{xcolor}
\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\colorbox{teal!30}{\qquad#1\qquad}}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{equation}
\begin{multlined}
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}
    \frac{(-1)^k(\alpha+k+\frac12) \sin \sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+k+\frac12)^2}}
         {(\beta^2+(2k+1)^2)\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+k+\frac12)^2}}   \\
    = \frac{\pi(\alpha+\frac12 i \beta)
                \sin\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}
         {4i\beta\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2}\beta)
                \sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}        \\
    - \frac{\pi(\alpha-\frac12 i \beta)
                \sin\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha-\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}
           {4i\beta\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2}\beta)\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha-\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}.
\end{multlined}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

or you like to have frame and colored text?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{empheq,
            amssymb}
\usepackage[dvipsname]{xcolor}
\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\qquad#1\qquad}}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{equation}
\color{red}
\begin{multlined}
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}
    \frac{(-1)^k(\alpha+k+\frac12) \sin \sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+k+\frac12)^2}}
         {(\beta^2+(2k+1)^2)\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+k+\frac12)^2}}   \\
    = \frac{\pi(\alpha+\frac12 i \beta)
                \sin\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}
         {4i\beta\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2}\beta)
                \sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}        \\
    - \frac{\pi(\alpha-\frac12 i \beta)
                \sin\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha-\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}
           {4i\beta\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2}\beta)\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha-\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}.
\end{multlined}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

note: since the equation is to wide that its number can be placed in line with equation, i broke it into three lines using `multlined` environment from `mathtools` (which is loaded by the package `empheq`). if yout liked this format of equation, you can insert your equation as you have with `split` environment.

if you like to change box line color and lines thickness than use `fcolorbox` (from the package `cxolor`). for example:

```
\newcommand*\widefbox[1]%
    {
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}% if you like to change box lines thicnes
    \fcolorbox{blue}{white}{\qquad#1\qquad}%
    }
```

and you will obtain:

[image]

(well, to my taste, this is to fancy :-( ).

Comment: you were to fast with comment, i need some time to upload the second possibility :-).

Comment: I thought you were hibernating. (+1)

Comment: @marmot, yesterday we change time to summer (+ 1 hour). since i'm not yet accommodate to this, i'm still wake up :-(. thank you very much!

Comment: These clashing with the set up I had for "\mybox{}". How can I resolve that.

Comment: @Fib1123, what is clashing? elaborate please.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposal based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413812/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]{\node(#1)[inner sep=0pt]{#2};}}

\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.8, .8, 1}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\tikznode{1}{\strut}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 
\frac{(-1)^k(\alpha+k+\frac12) \sin
\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+k+\frac12)^2}\tikznode{2}{\strut}}{(\beta^2+(2k+1)^2)\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+k+\frac12)^2}}
\\
&=\frac{\pi(\alpha+\frac12 i \beta)\sin\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}{4i\beta\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2}\beta)\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}
-
\frac{\pi(\alpha-\frac12 i \beta)\sin\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha-\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}{4i\beta\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2}\beta)\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha-\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}
\tikznode{3}{\strut}}.
\tikznode{4}{\strut}
\end{split}\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
\node[fit=(1) (2) (3) (4),fill=blue,fill opacity=0.25]{};}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
{\leavevmode\color{red}
\begin{split}
&\tikznode{5}{\strut}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 
\frac{(-1)^k(\alpha+k+\frac12) \sin
\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+k+\frac12)^2}\tikznode{6}{\strut}}{(\beta^2+(2k+1)^2)\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+k+\frac12)^2}}
\\
&=\frac{\pi(\alpha+\frac12 i \beta)\sin\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}{4i\beta\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2}\beta)\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha+\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}
-
\frac{\pi(\alpha-\frac12 i \beta)\sin\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha-\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}}{4i\beta\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2}\beta)\sqrt{b^2+\pi^2(\alpha-\frac{i}{2}\beta)^2}
\tikznode{7}{\strut}}.
\tikznode{8}{\strut}
\end{split}}\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
\node[fit=(5) (6) (7) (8),draw=blue,fill opacity=0.25]{};}
\end{equation}
\dots and back to black
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Explanation**: There are four nodes defined, `(1)`, `(2)`, `(3)` and `(4)` at some "extreme" positions. This allows one to make custom boxes without shifting the layout.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How to get rid of the background color ?

Comment: @Fib1123 Just replace `fill=blue` by `draw`.

Comment: in the latter you had the equation number colored as well. How to get rid of that ? Thank you.

Comment: @Fib1123 Please see my update.