# Box around an equation with multiple align marks

Tags: math-mode, align, mathtools

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview, border&=5bp]{standalone}
\usepackage{tfrupee, amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{5}
  \Aboxed{x + y &= 5 &&=15}\\
  \Aboxed{p + q &= 27}\\
      a + b &= 2 &&=11\\
      a + b &= 2 &&=11
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

The first equation with `Abox` is truncated, the second is not.

How do I get the box around the first equation also without truncation?

Comment: I don't really know what is going on there but you can try the solution of @SalimBou from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346577/boxed-and-align

Comment: Comment by **Henri Menke** from [\Aboxed with multiple & in align* environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223511/aboxed-with-multiple-in-align-environment): _`\Aboxed` can only have one & inside, because the macro is defined such that it reads all content up to the & and the content from the & to the end. Then the both parts are put into an `\fbox` and shifted right (by measuring the second half) such that they align with the rest._ They have `\fbox` solution there. Take a look at the link.